# Partial correlation - scales?

Tags: correlation, partial-correlation

Is there any way to conduct a partial correlation analysis if the DV is dichotomous?

Comment: If your purpose is to find the effect of a continuous variable on the dichotomous DV controlling for another continuous variable then maybe you should consider logistic regression.

Comment: Yes, I already conducted a logistic regression but was quite unsatisfied with the results

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't really a dependent variable in partial correlation; at least, the dependence of the two main variables (whose unmediated relationship is of interest – call 'em `x` and `y`) on the controlling variables is removed. The unexplained variance of `x` and `y`, i.e., the *residuals*, are the subjects of partial correlation. Once you have the residuals from linear models of `x` and `y` as predicted by your control variables, correlate them, and there you have your partial correlation.

A simple correlation between a continuous variable `z` and a dichotomous variable `y` is a [point-biserial correlation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Point-biserial_correlation_coefficient). OLS regression of the same two variables will produce this same correlation as a slope coefficient if the variables are standardized. The residuals of `y` regressed onto `z` (doesn't matter if you standardize the variables – the next step will have the same effect) can then be correlated with the residuals of a linear model of `x` regressed onto `z` to find the partial correlation between `x` and `y`.

Here's a brief demonstration in [r](/questions/tagged/r) in case anyone else finds it useful (I wanted to check my answer):

```
d8a=data.frame(y=rbinom(99,1,.5),x=rnorm(99),z=rnorm(99))                    #Simulated data
cor(lm(scale(y)~scale(z),d8a)$residuals,lm(x~z,d8a)$residuals)          #Base package method
require(ggm);pcor(c('x','y','z'),var(d8a))       #Dedicated function for partial correlation
```

The correlation of the residuals of the linear models of `x` and `y` as  predicted by `z` is the same as the result of the function dedicated to producing partial correlations. This is no surprise; this is all normal procedure for calculating partial correlations. The algebraic operations don't change when one variable is dichotomous. However, whether one should interpret a partial correlation the same way regardless of whether any variables are dichotomous is another question...(Comments welcome!)

BTW, [this article](http://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1207/s15327906mbr0703_9#.U2crOfldVCM) may be of tangential interest:
<sub>Bay, K. S., & Hakstianz, R. (1972). Note on the equivalence of the significance test of the partial point-biserial correlation and the one-factor analysis of covariance for two treatment groups. *Multivariate Behavioral Research, 7*(3), 391–395.</sub>